# Why isn't sbt finding this file which is at the Maven repository?

Tags: maven, sbt

I don't understand why `sbt` can't resolve a dependency.  All of a sudden today I've been getting this error:

```
[warn] ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn] :: com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-core;1.11.106: not found
```

`sbt.last.log` reports:

```
[warn] ==== maven-central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.106/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.106.pom
```

Yet I can web-browse to that folder and see the files `sbt` should find:

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.106/

com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.106
...
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.106.jar                    2017-03-20 23:44    840754
...
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.106.pom                    2017-03-20 23:44      4039
```

Comment: check contents of aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.106.pom  and see if you have a typo in your dependency name/ver etc.

Comment: With sbt 0.13.13 it gets fetch without any problems for me. Strange.

Comment: @MirMasej OK, I'll try 0.13.13.  This project was using 0.13.8.

Comment: @MirMasej 0.13.13 did it, thanks!  If you put that in as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use version 0.13.13 of SBT, it works.